# Close hotkey issue or crash?

Tags: interface

Is there a hotkey for quitting blender, because today as I was using blender I pressed (according to me) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo but I guess I pressed another key as well.

So was this a crash or just a hotkey?

Comment: Welcome ihab adeel :) Sounds like a crash for me, because normally there is a last dialog: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MKKh0.png Please try to reproduce the issue and send a bug report to the developers here: https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: I have also encountered this "bug" today several times.

Comment: The hotkey to quit Blender is `Ctrl+Q`, but it asks if you are sure before it shuts down (at least on Windows).